# How to get the domain that redirected to a page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to set up a rule in .htaccess that only applies if the requested page was redirected from a particular domain. That is to say, if xyz.com redirected to this page, I want it to redirect again to a different page. I thought of referer, but apparently the original referer is usually preserved. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the example you describe a user that clicks on link/form on Site A, is sent to Site B that redirects to your site and you want to know that the user came from Site B?

If yes, then if you cannot make a change to the code on Site B e.g. to insert an additional querystring parameter on the redirect (or if such a parameter already exists), then there is nothing in the request that will tell you that the user came from Site B i.e it is not possible.

Comment: You've accurately described my situation. I was hoping there was some other solution, but I guess that's the way it is.